# Which is the best way to Mock invoke aws ssm in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mocha.js

I'm trying mock a invoke service ssm to aws:

```
const ssm = require("../awsclients/aws-client");

const getSecret = async secretName => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(`Getting secret for ${secretName}`);
  const params = {
    Name: secretName,
    WithDecryption: true
  };

  const result = await ssm.getParameter(params).promise();
  return result.Parameter.Value;
};

module.exports = { getSecret };
```

Any suggestion, I'm new in nodeJS with AWS-Lambdas. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use stub/mock library like [sinon.js](https://sinonjs.org/).

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const ssm = require('./aws-client');

const getSecret = async (secretName) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(`Getting secret for ${secretName}`);
  const params = {
    Name: secretName,
    WithDecryption: true,
  };

  const result = await ssm.getParameter(params).promise();
  return result.Parameter.Value;
};

module.exports = { getSecret };
```

`aws-client.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  getParameter() {
    return this;
  },
  async promise() {
    return 'real value';
  },
};
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const { getSecret } = require('./');
const ssm = require('./aws-client');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('60695567', () => {
  it('should get secret', async () => {
    const promiseStub = sinon.stub().resolves({ Parameter: { Value: '123' } });
    sinon.stub(ssm, 'getParameter').callsFake(() => ({
      promise: promiseStub,
    }));
    const actual = await getSecret('token');
    expect(actual).to.be.eq('123');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(ssm.getParameter, { Name: 'token', WithDecryption: true });
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(promiseStub);
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
  60695567
Getting secret for token
    ✓ should get secret


  1 passing (25ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |      80 |      100 |   33.33 |      80 |                   
 aws-client.js |   33.33 |      100 |       0 |   33.33 | 3,6               
 index.js      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man !! your response works perfect !. I have to study sinon